# Get value of checkbox into angularjs $scope object

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-scope

Im new to angularjs and i'm stuck on this piece of code since 2 days.

I want to get values from selected checkboxes inside my angular js controller.

I have tried using ng-true-vlaue and ng-false-value as well but nothing works.

Moreover, Its safe to say that controller portion works fine. All i need to know is how to safely get the value from the checked checkbox to my $scope variables.

Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<div class="md-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox8" class="md-check" ng-model="InstallerType.installType" value="Install Kits Complete System"/>
                <label for="checkbox8">
                    <span></span>
                    <span class="check"></span>
                    <span class="box"></span>
                    Install Kits Complete System
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox9" class="md-check" ng-model="IndividualComponents.installType" value="Individual Components"/>
                <label for="checkbox9">
                    <span></span>
                    <span class="check"></span>
                    <span class="box"></span>
                    Individual Components
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox10" class="md-check" ng-model="ShippingToSite.installType" value="Shipping To Customer Site"/>
                <label for="checkbox10">
                    <span></span>
                    <span class="check"></span>
                    <span class="box"></span>
                    Shipping To Customer Site
                </label>
            </div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.InstallerType = {
    installType: ''        
};

$scope.IndividualComponents = {
    installType: ''
};

$scope.ShippingToSite = {
    installType: ''
};

$scope.$watch('addInstallerForm.$valid', function (newVal) {

    $scope.IsFormValid = newVal;

});

$scope.AddInstaller = function () {

    $scope.Submitted = true;
    if ($scope.IsFormValid) {
        InstallerService.AddNewInstaller($scope.Installer, $scope.InstallerSize, $scope.InstallerType, $scope.IndividualComponents, $scope.ShippingToSite, $scope.User).then(function (i, is, cs, ic, sts, u) {

            if (i.data.firstName != null) {
                $scope.IsLoggedIn = true;
                alert('Registration Successful.');
            }

            else {
                alert('Registration Failed.');
            }
        });
    }
};
```

})

**FACTORY**

```
var fac = {};
fac.AddNewInstaller = function (i, is, cs, ic, sts, u) {

    var obj = {};

    obj.i = i;
    obj.u = u;
    obj.is = is;
    obj.ic = ic;
    obj.cs = cs;
    obj.sts = sts;

    var string = JSON.stringify(obj);

    return $http({
        url: '/Database/AddNewInstaller',
        method: 'POST',
        data: string,
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }

    });

};
```

Comment: Have you seen the [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D#example)?

Comment: share your code somewhere. for example there: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add your form data to one `$scope` variable so you can work with the data on form submit or with `ng-click`.

E.g. your scope variable could look like this:

```
$scope.myForm = {
    InstallerType: false,
    IndividualComponents: false,
    ShippingToSite: false
};
```

But you could do any object structure you need for your app. Not sure why you've added `installType` to your object. Because the above should be OK to work with. Maybe you could think of grouping these three into one parent object if you have more stuff in the form.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndx1t9vj/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
.controller('mainController', MainController);


function MainController($scope, $window) {
 $scope.submit = function(form) {
     $window.alert('do somthing with form data: '+ JSON.stringify(form));
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <form ng-submit = "submit(myForm)">
        <div class="md-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox8" class="md-check" ng-model="myForm.InstallerType.installType" value="Install Kits Complete System"/>
                <label for="checkbox8">
                    <span></span>
                    <span class="check"></span>
                    <span class="box"></span>
                    Install Kits Complete System
                </label>
        </div>
            <div class="md-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox9" class="md-check" ng-model="myForm.IndividualComponents.installType" value="Individual Components"/>
                <label for="checkbox9">
                    <span></span>
                    <span class="check"></span>
                    <span class="box"></span>
                    Individual Components
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="md-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox10" class="md-check" ng-model="myForm.ShippingToSite.installType" value="Shipping To Customer Site"/>
                <label for="checkbox10">
                    <span></span>
                    <span class="check"></span>
                    <span class="box"></span>
                    Shipping To Customer Site
                </label>
            </div>
    <button tpye="submit">submit</button>
    {{myForm}}
    </form>


</div>
```